# Rectangular shape recognition from an image

Tags: c++, opencv, detection, rectangles

My work consists of a  detection of faults existing in the contour of flywheel. More precisely at surface of teeths  existing  on the contour of the steering wheel.

I want to capture a video of the contour of the steering wheel, I want to eventually extract photos from this video the result will be  an image containing the tooth with some details that which i will not need it.

**I only need to extract the tooth so I can compare it  after with a non-defective tooth  to conclude if there is or there isn't a defect**, since i only need the saw tooth and the tooth shape is rectangular, so I need to make a rectangular shape recognition.

I work with Eclipse C++ and OpenCV.

Now I'm following [this tutorial](http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/)

**Example image**

[image]

**Expected result**

[image]

Comment: Post a few images, expected result, and the code you're using to solve this

Comment: Hi thnx for the response , i would like to word with the same pricipe of this code to extract the touth wich has a rectangular form from an image contains the tooth , some détails existing around the tooth

Comment: Yeah, but there are a lot of methods. It mostly depends on your images. So please post a few, with expected result. (If you can't post images, post some public link to them)

Comment: I’m using this algorithm

Get the edge map.
Detect lines with Hough transform.
Get the corners by finding intersections between lines.
Check if the approximate polygonal curve has 4 vertices.
Determine top-left, bottom-left, top-right, and bottom-right corner.
Apply the perspective transformation

Comment: this is the link from where i founs the code :  http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/automatic-perspective-correction-for-quadrilateral-objects/                                                                                                           this is the code :      https://github.com/bsdnoobz/opencv-code/blob/master/quad-segmentation.cpp

Comment: Can i share the images on my google + account or  sir can i get your name eo ggole plus or your adress mail thnx

Comment: Edit your question and add public links to your images. Google Drive, imgur, whatever

Comment: [img]http://i.imgur.com/q11mgWH.png[/img]
[img]http://i.imgur.com/jHqsE9C.png[/img]
[img]http://i.imgur.com/xmqaxll.png[/img]

Comment: thanks, I'll edit into your question. But first, can you provide an image where you manually draw a rectangle on your detection? It'll be the expected result for you.

Comment: http://imgur.com/8QW6uWR

Comment: Edited your question. If there is other you want to add or change, edit it (click on the _edit_ link under the tags).

Comment: Can you also post the code you're using and some results? I guess it gives bad results for some images. (Remember to post also original images)

Comment: #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

cv::Point2f center(0,0);

cv::Point2f computeIntersect(cv::Vec4i a, 
                             cv::Vec4i b)
{
 int x1 = a[0], y1 = a[1], x2 = a[2], y2 = a[3], x3 = b[0], y3 = b[1], x4 = b[2], y4 = b[3];
 float denom;

 if (float d = ((float)(x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4)) - ((y1 - y2) * (x3 - x4)))
 {
  cv::Point2f pt;
  pt.x = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (x3 - x4) - (x1 - x2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / d;
  pt.y = ((x1 * y2 - y1 * x2) * (y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2) * (x3 * y4 - y3 * x4)) / d;
  return pt;
 }

Comment: else
  return cv::Point2f(-1, -1);
}

void sortCorners(std::vector<cv::Point2f>& corners, 
                 cv::Point2f center)
{
 std::vector<cv::Point2f> top, bot;

 for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++)
 {
  if (corners[i].y < center.y)
   top.push_back(corners[i]);
  else
   bot.push_back(corners[i]);
 }
 corners.clear();

Comment: if (top.size() == 2 && bot.size() == 2){
  cv::Point2f tl = top[0].x > top[1].x ? top[1] : top[0];
  cv::Point2f tr = top[0].x > top[1].x ? top[0] : top[1];
  cv::Point2f bl = bot[0].x > bot[1].x ? bot[1] : bot[0];
  cv::Point2f br = bot[0].x > bot[1].x ? bot[0] : bot[1];
 
  
  corners.push_back(tl);
  corners.push_back(tr);
  corners.push_back(br);
  corners.push_back(bl);
 }
}

Comment: int main()
{
 cv::Mat src = cv::imread("image.jpg");
 if (src.empty())
  return -1;

 cv::Mat bw;
 cv::cvtColor(src, bw, CV_BGR2GRAY);
 cv::blur(bw, bw, cv::Size(3, 3));
 cv::Canny(bw, bw, 100, 100, 3);

 std::vector<cv::Vec4i> lines;
 cv::HoughLinesP(bw, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 70, 30, 10);

 // Expand the lines
 for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
 {
  cv::Vec4i v = lines[i];
  lines[i][0] = 0;
  lines[i][1] = ((float)v[1] - v[3]) / (v[0] - v[2]) * -v[0] + v[1]; 
  lines[i][2] = src.cols; 
  lines[i][3] = ((float)v[1] - v[3]) / (v[0] - v[2]) * (src.cols - v[2]) + v[3];
 }

Comment: std::vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
 for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
 {
  for (int j = i+1; j < lines.size(); j++)
  {
   cv::Point2f pt = computeIntersect(lines[i], lines[j]);
   if (pt.x >= 0 && pt.y >= 0)
    corners.push_back(pt);
  }
 }

 std::vector<cv::Point2f> approx;
 cv::approxPolyDP(cv::Mat(corners), approx, cv::arcLength(cv::Mat(corners), true) * 0.02, true);

 if (approx.size() != 4)
 {
  std::cout << "The object is not quadrilateral!" << std::endl;
  return -1;
 }

Comment: // Get mass center
 for (int i = 0; i < corners.size(); i++)
  center += corners[i];
 center *= (1. / corners.size());

 sortCorners(corners, center);
 if (corners.size() == 0){
  std::cout << "The corners were not sorted correctly!" << std::endl;
  return -1;
 }
 cv::Mat dst = src.clone();

 // Draw lines
 for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++)
 {
  cv::Vec4i v = lines[i];
  cv::line(dst, cv::Point(v[0], v[1]), cv::Point(v[2], v[3]), CV_RGB(0,255,0));
 }

Comment: // Draw corner points
 cv::circle(dst, corners[0], 3, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 2);
 cv::circle(dst, corners[1], 3, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2);
 cv::circle(dst, corners[2], 3, CV_RGB(0,0,255), 2);
 cv::circle(dst, corners[3], 3, CV_RGB(255,255,255), 2);

 // Draw mass center
 cv::circle(dst, center, 3, CV_RGB(255,255,0), 2);

 cv::Mat quad = cv::Mat::zeros(300, 220, CV_8UC3);

 std::vector<cv::Point2f> quad_pts;
 quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
 quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, 0));
 quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(quad.cols, quad.rows));
 quad_pts.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, quad.rows));

Comment: cv::Mat transmtx = cv::getPerspectiveTransform(corners, quad_pts);
 cv::warpPerspective(src, quad, transmtx, quad.size());

 cv::imshow("image", dst);
 cv::imshow("quadrilateral", quad);
 cv::waitKey();
 return 0;
}

Comment: i'm sorry i was obliged to send the code in this way

Comment: http://imgur.com/reLs9Cj

Comment: Edit the code into your question!